# Ensuring only a single formula could ever apply to 4 random elements

Tags: c#, algorithm, permutation

I have a list of formulae for combining elements:

```
A + B + C = X
D + E + F = Y
G + H + I = Z
```

I want to ensure that given any random 4 elements, there will never be more than 1 applicable formula. For example the formulae below should not be allowed as if I get elements A, B, C and D then both are applicable:

```
A + B + C = X
B + C + D = Y
```

Every formula will consist of 3 elements on the LHS and it's the LHS that I want to enforce the rule on.  
The elements are sortable, if that helps.

---

An alternative, equivalent problem:

I have a list of an array of 3 elements: `List<Element[3]>` How do I ensure that no 2 elements appear in more than one array.

---

What would be a reasonably efficient (runtime speed) way of doing this for a large number of elements and a large number for formulae (beyond brute forcing)?

Comment: P.s. This isn't homework, i'm trying to create a game similar to [Gem Tower Defense](http://www.gemtowerdefense.com/)

Comment: this must be so advanced I don't even understand your question ¬_¬

Comment: 11.1k reputation and the homework tag would make for an interesting combination

Comment: @EugenRieck: It could be that I've switched languages. :)

Comment: @iamserious: Re-worded to hopefully clarify.

Comment: @dtb: The only way I can think so far is to get a list of all elements involved in all formulas, then brute force every combination of 4 of them, then for each combination, check that one or no formula applies. I'd imagine a better approach exists.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Even if you switched languages, you wouldn't ask for an algorithm: If you can work a Philips-style screwdriver with 11.1k RPM, you are unlikely to ask "How do I hold a Pozidrive"

Comment: I don't understand. The constraint is on the terms on the left-hand side only? Terms can appear in arbitrarily many equations, so long as pairs of terms co-occur in only one equation? Could we add `A+E+I=W` to the set of equations? `A+E+I=X`?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber: The constraint is on the LHS only. Yes you could add either of those 2.

Comment: @EugenRieck: I'm pretty good with C# and could write something to get the job done, but I'm sure my approach wouldn't be an optimal one as I'm not overly familiar with Big-O theory. In the same way someone very good at using a screwdriver might want to ask others how they would construct a desk with the minimum number of screws.

Comment: What are your left hand side elements? Is there a way to normalize their order (i.e. to sort them)?

Comment: @Groo: Conceptually they don't sort, but they do have a sortable Id, so they could be sorted for use with an algorithm.

Comment: Always exactly three elements per equation?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber: Yes, sorry I thought I included all info in the question, but I clearly haven't.

Comment: And what about elements' address space? Is it relatively small? E.g. in the range of "uppercase letter only"? [Edit] Never mind, I just noticed *for a large number of elements and a large number for formulae*.

Comment: In that case, the alternative problem isn't equivalent; it's more general.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber: Good catch, I've edited that version of the problem.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett, aah, yes, it is much better now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent the constraints on the set of equations as a graph. The vertices are the elements, with `n[i]` elements in equation `i`. For equation `i`, there are thus `n[i]*(n[i]-1)/2` pairs of elements; these become edges. Iterate through the equations, adding the edges to the graph. Anytime you'd want to add an edge that is already present, you've found a conflict.

For each edge, you could store a set of equation numbers that would generate the edge; this allows the specific conflicts to be identified, rather than just the presence of conflicts.

Let `N` be the number of equations and `M` the number of elements in the equation with the most elements. The time complexity is `O(M^2*N)`, as is the space complexity. If all equations have a fixed number of elements, time and space usage will thus be `O(N)`.

Comment: Depending on your representation of the graph, this may not be O(N) IMO. How do you store the graph, i.e. do you check if an edge is already present (what's the time complexity for that operation)? I am asking because O(N) space doesn't usually relate to O(1) lookup time in graph algorithms, but I may easily be missing a point.

Comment: @Groo We don't do much with the graph, so there are a lot of possibilities that will work here. Since we don't need to look up the vertices, the simplest is probably just to have a hash table mapping the edges to sets of equation numbers.

Comment: "For each edge, you could store a set of equation numbers that would generate the edges; this allows the specific conflicts to be identified, rather than just the presence of conflicts."  Even to infer presence of conflicts you need to store equation numbers associated with each edge. Eg. (for M=4), you can have edges between A,B & C even though A,B&C might not appear in the same equation. You would have to get a set of equations associated with A-B and intersect them with the corresponding sets of B-C and A-C to see if they all appear in the same equation. Probably your solution is not O(N).

Comment: @ElKamina That is not correct. The constraint is that no pair of elements appears in more than one equation; this is easier to see from the alternative formulation given by the OP. With three elements on the LHS, this approach generates three edges from each of the N equations, thus 3N edges and it's linear. Nothing more need be done.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber Can you give me a specific example with M=4 ? Assume equation exists for ABMN, BCOP, ACQR. I want to check if ABCD is possible?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber I have added a solution inspired by your solution. See if they are equivalent. Mine is of complexity O(mnlog(mn)) . FWIW, hash table lookup complexity is O(log(n)), not O(1).

Answer (score 2):

Essentially this comes down to a exclusion problem: From your example data,

- the first formula works on the set (A,B,C,X) or maybe (A,B,C) if X is
  a constant
- the second formula works on (D,E,F,Y) or (D,E,F)
- etc

and you want to make sure, that any new entry to the list

- Doesn't operate on a set already in the list (like (A,B,C[,X]))
- Doesn't operate on a subset of an entry already in the list (like (A,B)), as in this case the input tuple (A,B,C[,X]) would work on an already existing formula AND the new one

Depending on the size of the tuples, creating an exhaustive list of subsets can be expensive or not

This should work on small sets (cheap listing of subsets)

```
Keep dictionary of formulas
On new formula
  Normalize variable list (e.g. (D,A,c)=>"ACD")
  Check if normalized variable list exists in dictionary
  If it exists, reject new formula and break
  For all subsets of variable list
    Check if normalized variable list of subset exists in dictionary
    If it exists, reject new formula and break
  End For
End On
```

Comment: +1 Hashtable is O(1), and there are only 3 pairs per tuple, so this is also O(N).

Answer (score 1):

This solution is inspired by Michael J. Barber's solution.

1. Initialize a hash table
2. When you have a equation with M variables, add all combinations with size M-1 to the hash table. Eg: For A+B+C+D=Z, add (A,B,C), (A,B,D), (A,C,D) and (B,C,D)
3. When you want to test possibility of a new equation with M variables, check if all the M-1 subsets are NOT in the hash.

Complexity: O(mnlog(mn) ).

Answer (score 0):

You could define that problem from other side: There isn't any pair of formulas that union of elements contains less than 5 elements. Which points to algorithm that compares each pair of formulas if they pass that test. I know that its brute force but i can't realy imagine anything better atm.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could utilize some of the LINQ set operations. Since you described your problem as having a list of lists, wanting to *"ensure that no 2 elements appear in more than one list"*, couldn't that also be described as checking whether there exists a intersection between any of the lists? Or am I a bit off here?

James Michael Hare has [a nice article on the various set operations](http://blackrabbitcoder.net/archive/2011/05/05/c.net-little-wonders-the-linq-set-operations----theyre-not.aspx) available in LINQ. You could start by having a look there :-)

Comment: Or would it (according to your example with formulas made up by 3 elements, and given any 4 random elements) be more correct to describe it so that you want to make sure there doesn't exist any intersection between any two formulas with more than _one_ element in the intersection?

Answer (score -1):

Store your values in a matrix and ensure that matrix[i][j] != matrix[k][j] with i != k.

**Update:**

This approach if often used when solving linear equations problems. Elements in the matrix represents coefficients of polynomial functions. You can then operate between rows to take the matrix to special forms.

But in this case you just only need to store your elements in a matrix and validate the matrix before adding a row (some combination of elements).

This approach has the advantage as being the most efficient but you will need to handle correctly the initial size and the resizing strategy.

**Update 2:**

```
A + B + C = X
B + C + D = Y

m[0][1] = B
m[1][0] = B
```

This examples breaks the rule matrix[i][j] != matrix[k][j] with i != k

Then you can't use formulae B + C + D = Y because of A + B + C = X.

Comment: What do the indices represent? Elements in both cases?

Comment: Could you expand this approach please? I have heard of representing formulae in matrices in relation to solving them for given variables, however I don't understand how to apply it to this case.

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit? How do you 1. "store your elements" and 2. "validate the matrix"? Even if the element space was small, I don't understand the indices in your first equation.

Comment: This answer isn't very clear, but looks wrong to me. As the rule is expressed, it appears to say that no variable can appear twice in a given column. But we know that `A+E+I=W` can be added to the equations given by the OP. Take just `A+B+C=X` and `A+E+I=W`, and we have `m[0][0]=m[1][0]=A`, which you say should be forbidden. The approach is also by no means the "most efficient"; you'll need to check all previous rows, giving O(N^2) time for N equations.